# Site is redirecting to 404 page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am getting this strange situation. I have a site blahblah.com hosted on shared hosting. When I hit that site it is redirecting to this in chrome

```
blahblah.com/sitefoldername/site/404
```

my custom errors mode is "Off" and thats it. Nothing else is there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try full url with pagename?

if it works, you may need to set default page under GoDaddy web server settings.